# how can i sort the result set to the order used in the 'in' the sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I will explain using a sample situation

say i have a mysql table **tbl_student**

[image]

and with the following example data

[image]

when i run the query

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_student` WHERE `rollno` in (5,25,1)
```

i get this

[image]

Which is great but i was looking for a method to **sort the result to the order 5,25,1 instead of 1,5,25**  I mean preserve the order used in the 'in' .

In my program i can always use a php function to re-order the data .But i am wondering if there is a sql only means to do this which could make things much easy or using the script the only way.

I am looking for the best way to solve this .

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(rollno, 5, 25, 1)
```